# Cypher variable lenght pattern aggregated property filtering

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on neo4j and I'm trying to put a condition on a series of relationships, where I need to sum a property of said relationship.
When I do the basic textbook part of filtering for the relationship without the sum, it all works.

```
    MATCH c= (a)-[:VENDE*2..3]->(b)
    WHERE ALL (r IN relationships(c)
    WHERE r.ammontare = 25000)
    RETURN c
```

When I try to put the condition on the sum of said property, I can't find a way.
I tried REDUCE but it's stuck because the this error I didn't manage to work around: "Type mismatch: accumulator is Integer but expression has type Boolean"

```
    MATCH c= (a)-[:VENDE*2..3]->(b)
    WHERE ALL (r IN relationships(c)
    WHERE REDUCE( t = 0, n in relationships(c)|t= t+ n.ammontare) = 25000)
    RETURN c
```

I tried with apoc but this doesn't work either. What am I getting wrong?

```
    MATCH c= (a)-[:VENDE*2..3]->(b)
    WHERE all(r in relationships(r)
    WHERE  APOC.COLL.SUM( [r IN relationships(c)| r.ammontare]) = 25000)
    return c
```

The last method runs but it's too heavy and goes into timeout.

```
    MATCH c= (a)-[:VENDE*2]->(b)
    WITH c, relationships(c) as rels
    UNWIND (rels) as rel
    With c, sum(rel.ammontare) as re
    where re > 25000
    return c
```

Comment: On the error "n.ammontare has type Boolean", you can check the data type if integer before adding it.

Comment: The (n) in relationships part is boolean I think, but the  thing I'm trying to sum is not n, is n.ammontare that is not boolean at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this will work.

```
    MATCH c= (a)-[:VENDE*2..3]->(b)
    WHERE ALL (r IN relationships(c)
    WHERE REDUCE( t = 0, n in relationships(c)| t+ n.ammontare) = 25000)
    RETURN c
```